# How to store file from .exe in desired folder?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I have a python script, which I have successfully converted to .exe file using pyinstaller. Somehow, the icon doesn't show up, if I could get some help/tip w/ that. It was stored as .icns file as I work on a mac.

Main issue here is, my python script writes a .csv file. When I run the .exe file, the csv saves to the main user folder, and not the same folder as the exe file. How do I solve this? I have tried googling and every other method, but doesn't work.

One solution is to direct to the folder using command-line and then type './file.exe'.
But I am really looking for an option, which gets this done by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While saving the .csv file, you can use os.getcwd()+'/file.csv'. Hope this might help.